# Importing file into Postgresql failing notwithstanding absence of modifiers

Tags: postgresql

When launching an import in postgresql

```
COPY users FROM '/Volumes/deploy/users_test.tsv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
>  ERROR:  missing data for column "current_sign_in_at"
```

Oddly, a few days ago this did not occur with the same file.  Although changes were made to the user table, the request for this fields seems inappropriate as:

```
        Column         |              Type              |                     Modifiers                      | Storage  |
current_sign_in_at     | timestamp without time zone    |                                                    | plain    |
nation_id              | bigint                         |                                                    | plain    |              |
status_id              | integer                        |                                                    | plain    |              |
sex_id                 | integer                        |                                                    | plain    |
mobile                 | bigint                         |                                                    | plain    |
```

the column is not a requirement for a valid entry (null is false).  I furthered the exeperiment by adding the asked for columns... until it asked for `nation_id` which was already provided.  The most dumbed-down import file:

```
nation_id,status_id,sex_id,mobile,email,login_name,encrypted_password,created_at,updated_at,sign_in_count
1,3,1,33967258079,'ze@big.boss','ze@big.boss','$2a$10$lZrj8nzt.Sx05DJ7ZMnsiOKfq8iArTJQ2zKZgGXzJi2v16AKSGp7C','2020-11-18 09:13:09','2020-11-18 09:13:09',0
```

If data is inserted individually:

```
INSERT INTO users (nation_id,status_id,sex_id,mobile,email,login_name,encrypted_password,created_at,updated_at,sign_in_count) VALUES (1,3,1,33967258079,'ze@big.boss','ze@big.boss','$2a$10$lZrj8nzt.Sx05DJ7ZMnsiOKfq8iArTJQ2zKZgGXzJi2v16AKSGp7C','2020-11-18 09:13:09','2020-11-18 09:13:09',0);
```

the data is saved.

The behaviour of both actions points to an issue with the header.  What needs to be fixed?

Comment: When you say changes where made to the user table do you mean  the `current_sign_in_at` field was added? `COPY` will not ignore fields when there is not a field specification list. This is another way of saying `HEADER` just ignores the first line on import and does nothing with that information. You will have to specify a column list to `COPY` that matches the names and order of the columns in the table.

Comment: thus... `COPY users(nation_id,status_id,sex_id,mobile,email,login_name,encrypted_password,created_at,updated_at,sign_in_count) FROM ...`  yup!  silly to have done it with `INSERT` and not `COPY`